Accept only string_view pointing to static storage string literals in compilation time without template
Context

There is a class using different callback with different sets of data and wants to give them different kind of "name" for logging.

X kind of Data: [email address, geo address, user name]
Y kind of evaluation: [starts_with, hash, ends_with, ...etc ]


It's quite similar to different "type" of Object with different kind of data plus the logic. So using enum would be tedious since X kinds of data and Y evaluation could result in X*Y number of combinations.

I want to have some code for logging which pointing to certain static storage string literals.
Taking a simple std::string_view from constructor to a private member seems fine but I want to prevent future maintainers from feeding non-static storage strings...
Note: this seems like a duplicate of C++: Constructor accepting only a string literal but the answers were written in template.
Goal and presumptions:

There would be known number of static string literals in compilation time.
Multiple objects would point to the same static string literals and I'd like to avoid using std::string.
Avoid std::string_view pointing to a temporary data.

Solutions so far with template or enum:

string literal to template argument
A callback as a template argument
But I don't want to write template code just for logging with names...
Using a enum and lookup the enum in logging would work as well. I'm fed up with adding enum and reverse lookup enum into strings... This would be my final solution if there is no other solutions.

Solution requirements:

Accept C++20 and above solutions. Even it's in C++23 or C++26, at least I know it could be solved in the future. Appreciate if there is a solution for C++20.
Maybe this is a XY problem. Please let me know if there is another way to solve it.

Live Demo without restriction
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

static constexpr std::string_view EXACT = "exact";
static constexpr std::string_view PREFIX = "prefix";

class Evaluator{
public:
    Evaluator(std::string_view name) : m_name(name){}
    bool evaluate(std::string_view input){
        // Work for lookup per input
        // ...
        // Logging
        std::cout << m_name << "\n";
        return true;
    }
private:
    std::string_view m_name;

};

int main(){
    Evaluator exact(EXACT);
    exact.evaluate("");
    Evaluator prefix(PREFIX);
    prefix.evaluate("");
}

Live Demo for template version
static constexpr const char CEXACT[] = "exact";
static constexpr const char CPREFIX[] = "prefix";

template<const char* name>
class Evaluator{
public:
    Evaluator() : m_name(name){}
    bool evaluate(std::string_view input){
        // Work for lookup per input
        std::cout << m_name << "\n";
        return true;
    }
private:
    std::string_view m_name;
};



You say: "Maybe this is a XY problem" -- it probably is, but no one can tell you without knowing why you want this in the first place. Also it seems to me, the string doesn't necessarily have to live in static storage, it just has to outlive the Evaluator instance. So std::string s; std::getline(s, std::cin); Evaluator e(s); should work fine as well. And really, if it's just about storing a few characters for the name, just make a copy by using std::string instead.

If it's about logging. You'd better use  std::format_string - which is essentially created at compile-time(consteval ctor) - along with std::format or C++23 std::println.

Hi @chrysante, thanks.. I added the context. Hope that helps. Also agree std::string might be simplest way.

Even with your clarification, I don't understand your train of thought. All I can tell is you are troubled with lifetime issues. That has nothing to do with string literals. You either make it abundantly clear to users that they are responsible for the lifetime of the referred object and that it must outlive your object, or you are responsible for the lifetime. Forcing users to only use static objects make no sense because that's not your actual requirement.

Thanks @PasserBy. I think whether 1) forcing users to take care of it 2) adding a convention to it might be enough.  3) Force source data outlive Evaluator.

Use a compile-time string implementation.  This is an object that contains the actual string and is consteval throughout.
Write a pseudo-string-view that wraps such a compile-time string.
The first one is going to be template class (so as not to waste storage).  The 2nd will have a template constructor from said template class, but internally be just a pair of pointers.  You could even use a string_view internally, with various degrees of DRY failure and/or possible "security holes" to allow someone to actively bypass the type restriction.
Use would look like:
static constexpr ct_string EXACT = "exact";
static constexpr ct_string CPREFIX = "prefix";

or
static constexpr auto EXACT = "exact"_ct;
static constexpr auto CPREFIX = "prefix"_ct;

and at point of consumption:
bool evaluate(ct_string_view input){
  // Work for lookup per input
  std::cout << m_name << "\n";
  return true;
}

Internally, ct_string ends up being a consteval null-terminated array of characters.

Thanks for the answer. Could you improve my approach or add my approach to your answer if this is what you explained? https://godbolt.org/z/4hvPGTnY8

@LouisGo Use user literals to improve creation, so "foo"_ctv gives you a compile-time view.  Consier inheriting from std::string_view and adding your own constructors (someone can attack this via slicing, but are you assuming a hostile user?  If you want to deal with modestly hostile users, inherit privately and use using base::method to bring allowed methods into your class).
